# codeigniter getting data array inside a datatable column

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, datatable

I want to view multiple arrays in my data table row. I'm not sure how to do this. Data table only queries what is inside the `_get_datatables_query`. I cannot query for other referenced data.

[image]

```
public function list_projects() {
  $list = $this->foo_pro->get_datatables();
  $data = array();
  $ProjectID = $_POST['start'];
  foreach ($list as $foo_pro) {
    $ProjectID++;
    $row = array();
    // $row[] = $no;
    $row[] = $foo_pro->P_Year.$foo_pro->Code.$foo_pro->ProjectID;
    $row[] = $foo_pro->Contractor_Name;
    $row[] = $foo_pro->User_Title.'. '.$foo_pro->Dp_LastName;
    $row[] = '<div style="">&#8369;'.number_format($foo_pro->Contract_Amount, 2).'</div>';
    $row[] = $foo_pro->FirstName.' '.$foo_pro->Initial.'. '.$foo_pro->LastName.' #'.$foo_pro->Control_No;
    $row[] = '';
    $row[] = '';
    $row[] = '';
    $data[] = $row;
  }

  $output = array(
    "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
    "recordsTotal" => $this->foo_pro->count_all(),
    "recordsFiltered" => $this->foo_pro->count_filtered(),
    "data" => $data,
  );
  //output to json format
  echo json_encode($output);
}
```

What I want to achieve are array in 1 row and 1 column.

#### my join query.

```
$this->db->from($this->table);
$this->db->group_by('project.ProjectID');
$this->db->join('contractor', 'contractor.Contractor_No = project.Contractor_No');
$this->db->join('dpwh_user', 'dpwh_user.DPWH_User_No = project.DPWH_User_No');
$this->db->join('contractor_user', 'contractor_user.Contractor_User_No = project.Contractor_User_No');
$this->db->join('qcp', 'qcp.ProjectID = project.ProjectID');
$this->db->join('designmix', 'designmix.ProjectID = project.ProjectID');
$this->db->join('monthlyreport', 'monthlyreport.ProjectID = project.ProjectID');
```

[image]

Comment: If this came from two tables then why you don't try using join query to get the data from the database.  @HanthonyTagam

Comment: i actually posted the joined statement but it was edited then.

Answer (score 1):

In question if you have mentioned two tables than please find below mentioned query to get it done.

```
SELECT 
    p.ProjectId,
    p.Year,
    p.code,
    p.contract_amount,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|',CONCAT_WS('|',mr.month,mr.year),CONCAT(mr.completion,'% <br/>'))) as monthly_report
FROM project p
INNER JOIN monthly_report mr
GROUP BY p.ProjectId;
```

Also I have added `<br/>` in `group_concate()` function so when you render this output in browser it will add break as per your requirement.

Let me know if it not works.

#### [Working SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a670bf/2/0)

Comment: @ankitsuthar: Glad and Thank you for SQL Fiddle.

Comment: @HanthonyTagam : Let me know if it not works or other requirement

Comment: @ShyamShingadiya looks like that `<br>` is not working properly in the query.

Comment: @ankitsuthar : `<br>` I have just added because he wants monthly reports in each new lines, Also while fetching this in @HanthonyTagam can remove `<br>` with `str_replcae` and add `<br>` tag.

Comment: yes i get that appreciate that. but it's not working may be. because it's look like this in result `Mar|2016|50% <br/>,Jan|2016|20% <br/>,Feb|2016|24% <br/>`

Comment: There is again another option, in query add `\n` in `concat_ws` and while printing in html use `nl2br()` function, I hope this will help

Comment: I get it little late that the `<br>` will work at the view. not in the SQL.

Comment: @ankitsuthar : If non of above method help than best option is to `explode(delimiter,array)` result with `,` and then use `foreach` loop and add `<br>`.

Comment: @ShyamShingadiya your answer was on point but i was looking for a syntax that is compatible with codeigniter model support regarding the concatenation..

Answer (score 0):

Tho the response to this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45488903/codeigniter-getting-data-array-inside-a-datatable-column/45498353?noredirect=1#comment77989574_45498353) here is the query 
in active record technique.

Actually codeigniter is not very good when it comes to handle the subquerys. (as per my knowledge) I have added two options to work with subquerys. if both the querys will not get you what you wnat then i will suggest to use `$this->db->query();`.

I have not tested it yet.

#### option 1

```
$query = $this->db
    ->select('GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|',CONCAT_WS('|',mr.month,mr.year),CONCAT(mr.completion,'% <br/>'))) as monthly_report, p.ProjectId,p.Year,p.code,p.contract_amount,')    
    ->from('project p')
    ->join('monthly_report mr', 'mr.ProjectId = p.ProjectId', 'left')                               
    ->group_by('p.ProjectId')                   
    ->get();
```

#### option 2

```
$subquery = "(select GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|',CONCAT_WS('|',mr.month,mr.year),CONCAT(mr.completion,'% <br/>'))) as monthly_report 
            from monthly_report as mr
            where mr.ProjectId = p.ProjectId)";

$query = $this->db
    ->select('p.ProjectId,p.Year,p.code,p.contract_amount') 
    ->select($subquery) 
    ->from('project p')
    ->join('monthly_report mr', 'mr.ProjectId = p.ProjectId', 'left')                               
    ->group_by('p.ProjectId')                   
    ->get();
```